# reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Tags: java

I do not know what is going on with my code, it shows error reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

```
public class histogram{
public int largestRectangleArea(int height[]) {
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < height.length; i++) {
        max = Math.max(max, getArea(height, i));
    }
    return max;
}
private int getArea(int height[], int i) {
    int area = height[i];
    for (int j = i+1; j < height.length; j++) {
        if (height[j] >= height[i]) {
            area += height[i];
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    for (int j = i-1; j > -1; j--) {
        if (height[j] >= height[i]) {
            area += height[i];
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return area;
}

 public static void main(String[] args)  
 { 
    int height[] = { 2, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3}; 
    System.out.println("Maximum area is " + largestRectangleArea(height,        height.length)); 
} 
}
```

the largestRectangleArea(height, height.length)); in main function is error

Comment: The `largestRectangleArea` method is defined to take in a single parameter (an array of ints), but you're trying to call it with two arguments.

Comment: @Jordan I change to largestRectangleArea(height.length)); still has error Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verboseto get full output

Comment: Yes, that will still cause an error.  The method is defined as `largestRectangleArea(int height[])`, which means that you have to pass in an integer *array* as an argument.  `height.length` is just an integer, and not an array.  You should try using `largestRectangleArea(height)`